# How to convert string with Unicode literal characters in it to a Unicode string

Tags: c#, unicode

I am receiving data from an API (through C# code) in its literal form. Some of this data has non-ASCII characters in it. One example is shown below:

```
string universityName = "Universidad de M\u00e1laga";
```

I will be inserting this data into a SQL Server database, and would like to insert the Unicode encoded version, not the literal version. To do so, I need to encode the string correctly before inserting it. It should look like:

```
Universidad de Málaga
```

I've looked around Stack Overflow but can't seem to find a related question, so I thought I'd ask. Is there a built-in C# library that allows me to give it the original string and have it return the desired string? If not, is there a process I should follow?

I've already tried using `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` to get the bytes of the string and then convert it back into a string, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I could be using it wrong too.

Comment: By API do you mean via HTTP? If so, please [edit] your question to include the HTTP response header Content-Type value. Is there a particular reason you are putting the body into a text datatype when it is not the text you expect? Please show the code for that.

Comment: What does the string look like in the database with your current code? Please show the code you're trying that isn't working correctly (and describe *how* it isn't working).

Comment: Your original string appears as `"Universidad de Málaga"` in the debugger, so it seems correct. Is your column a `VARCHAR ` or an `NVARCHAR ` type? It's not clear to me exactly where the problem is (is it getting stored incorrectly? if so, what does it look like in the database?).

Comment: If you are calling a REST-like API that returns JSON, you should learn about that and probably use a popular library or two so you can fully handle everything that might be returned instead of just this one sample value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, however this might work for you.

<sub>***Disclaimer**: it's assumed your string looks like this in your db, `Universidad de M\u00e1laga`*</sub>

```
var test1 = "Universidad de M\\u00e1laga";  
var test2 = Regex.Unescape(test1);
Console.WriteLine(test1);
Console.WriteLine(test2);
```

Output

```
Universidad de M\u00e1laga
Universidad de Málaga
```

<sub>***Note** : This maybe pointing to an overall structural or design problem with this entire situation. Though, who knows what APIs give you back*</sub>

[**Full demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/59mxWt)

Comment: Why `Regex.Unescape`? Is this string a regular expression? Although it seems to work on this particular string, I think it isn't really robust solution.

Comment: When I try this on my string (vsq\u0005) I get a "vsq\u0005" as the output. What am I doing wrong?

Both of these give the same output.
   var t1 = Regex.Unescape("vsq\\u0005");
   var t2 = Regex.Unescape("vsq\u0005");

Answer (score 0):

The string you are showing contains a [Unicode character escape sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa664669%28v=vs.85%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which is a way for encoding characters inside C# strings, and it is used mainly for non-printable characters, but can be used for any character. For example all strings bellow are equal:

```
"ab"
"\u0061b"
"a\u0062"
"\u0061\u0062"
```

You can confirm it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("ab" == "\u0061b"); // True
Console.WriteLine("ab" == "a\u0062"); // True
Console.WriteLine("ab" == "\u0061\u0062"); // True
```

In your case:

```
Console.WriteLine("M\u00e1laga" == "Málaga"); // True
```

Long story short, you don't have to do anything. Your string is perfectly fine. Just store it in the DB!